# How to install a Windows service with Inno Setup?

Tags: service, inno-setup

I wrote a batch script to execute after my installation that is made with Inno Setup. The problem is that I have the following command line for my service creation:

```
sc create MySQL start= auto DisplayName= MySQL binPath= "C:\MyApp\MySQL 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\MyApp\MySQL 5.5\my.ini"
```

The letters with accents are the problem of this code, I can't execute it if I open the bat file in cmd, but when I type the service is created normally. How can I fix that?

Comment: You could use `AfterInstall` and then `Exec` function or `[Run]` `Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "sc create MySQL start= auto DisplayName= MySQL binPath= ""C:\A Nova Solução Informática\MySQL 5.5\bin\mysqld"" --defaults-file=""C:\A Nova Solução Informática\MySQL 5.5\my.ini"""; Flags: runhidden`

Comment: Try to add `CHCP 65001` at the beginning of your batch file and save it as UTF-8 without BOM. @Roben, or just `[Run]` section.

Comment: @RobeN, your solution partially helped me, the problem is that after the instalation of the service, the cmd process stay opened and the instalation don't finalize itself.

Answer (score 16):

Rather than calling SC directly, it's cleaner (and easier to deal with any errors or service dependencies) to [use the API](https://web.archive.org/web/20170823162031/http://vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Service_-_Functions_to_Start%2C_Stop%2C_Install%2C_Remove_a_Service).  Note that this example assumes that you're using ANSI Inno, but it's fairly straightforward to modify this for Unicode.

Personally, though, I prefer to build install/start/stop/uninstall commands into the service executable itself, making it self-registering.  Obviously this isn't possible to do yourself for a third-party service, but you could check to see if it already supports something like this.

One final point is that you must not hard-code the path to a C: folder.  You should be using `{app}` instead.

Comment: Do you have a Unicode version of the API already? I would need it very much. Thank you!

Comment: @MaikenRoskilde If you're using Unicode Inno Setup, then simply change the `A` suffix just prior to the `@` sign in the `external` entries to a `W` instead.  No other changes should be required.

Comment: The linked script by Silvio Iaccarino did not work for me. I was using Unicode Inno Setup and tried changing the suffixes as suggested but still didn't get it to work. I kept getting an error: "servicemanager is not available" or similar. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416744/207981) for an alternative script/library that **did** work for me.

Comment: It's cleaner, but it's like 1TB code just for that !?!

Comment: It's hardly that big, especially when compiled.  If it bothers you, you can extract most of it to a file that you can #include as needed.  (Or use the library that bszom linked to, which did it for you already.)

Answer (score 4):

You could try to add this command to `[RUN]` section (as TLama suggested) or create `AfterInstall` function in `[CODE]` section.

```
[Run] 
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "sc create MySQL start= auto DisplayName= MySQL 
binPath= ""C:\MyApp\MySQL 5.5\bin\mysqld"" 
--defaults-file=""C:\MyApp\MySQL 5.5\my.ini"""; 
Flags: runhidden
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this code? I am trying to use this code but it does not work. The cmd window will just pop up and do nothing.

Comment: @Govs did you try with `/c` at the beginning of `Parameters` (`cmd /c sc ...`), or just `Filename: "sc"; Parameters: "create ..."`

Comment: `Filename: "sc"; Parameters: "create service_name start= auto DisplayName= display_name binPath= ""{sys}\service_name.exe"""; Flags: runascurrentuser runhidden` works for me

Comment: @bartolo-otrit two syntaxes : (yours) `Filename: "{sys}\sc.exe"; Parameters:"create ..."`or  `Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters:"sc create ..."` I really would like to know the subtleties?

Comment: @Sandburg Concerning direct call vs indirect call by a command line I don't have any subtleties to share this time, but it looks like an indirect call is unneeded in this case.