# Install MySQL service in Inno Setup

Tags: mysql, windows-services, inno-setup

I would like to install MySQL service after install in `Inno Setup`. There is already similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204587/how-to-install-a-windows-service-with-inno-setup), but no solution there works for me.

If I use `sc create` like that in the solution, then after installation command promt just pop up, but doesn't do anything.

I tried modify command according some page, it works great in cmd:

```
sc create "MySQLSW" binpath= "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Drevarska spolecnost\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld\" --defaults-file=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Drevarska spolecnost\my.ini\" MySQLSW" DisplayName= "MySQLSW" start= "auto"
```

For Inno Setup it needs to be double quoted, so I tried this and few variants of it

```
[Run] 
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "sc create ""MySQLSW"" binpath= ""\""{app}\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld\"" --defaults-file=\""{app}\my.ini\"" MySQLSW"" DisplayName= ""MySQLSW"" start= ""auto""";
```

But cmd won't execute anything. Problem could be with that backslash, but I don't know the correct syntax.

I also tried add API from [here](https://github.com/pgina/pgina/blob/master/Installer/scripts/services.iss) and use following code, but there must be something wrong too, because it just pass installation, but won't create service.

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if IsServiceInstalled('MySQLSW') = false then begin
      if InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe'),ExpandConstant('--defaults-file="{app}\my.ini"'),'MySQLSW','Needed for mysql database',SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START) = true then begin
        StartService('MySQLSW');
      end
    end
    else if IsServiceRunning('MySQLSW') then
        MsgBox('MySQLSW is running',mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

I'm not much skilled in this yet, but I'm sure, there would be some misplaced quote somewhere, but I can't find it. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason why your `[Run]` call didn't work is that you forgot the `/c` parameter to `{cmd}`.  But using `{cmd}` was entirely unnecessary -- you could have just called sc directly.  However the final solution of using the service API directly is better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found at least one strange point.

InstallService definition by https://github.com/pgina/pgina/blob/master/Installer/scripts/services.iss:

```
function InstallService(FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;ServiceType,StartType :cardinal) : boolean;
```

Your call

```
InstallService(ExpandConstant('{app}\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe'),ExpandConstant('--defaults-file="{app}\my.ini"'),'MySQLSW','Needed for mysql database',SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START)
```

Are you sure ServiceName may contain such things?

FileName    - ExpandConstant('{app}\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe')
**ServiceName - ExpandConstant('--defaults-file="{app}\my.ini"')**
DisplayName - 'MySQLSW'
Description - 'Needed for mysql database'
ServiceType - SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
StartType   - SERVICE_AUTO_START

Try this

```
InstallService(ExpandConstant('"{app}\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe"') + ExpandConstant(' --defaults-file="{app}\my.ini" MySQLSW'), 'MySQLSW' ,'MySQLSW','Needed for mysql database',SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START)
```

Comment: It is very good when an answer explain what's the source of the problem, but you may consider to include an example of how the correct way to do it should look.

Comment: I wasn't sure, where to put that --defaults-file, on some page they used it in that ServiceName, so I was assumming it would be correct and searching problem somewhere else... Neverthless it is working now, I just needed to add name of service behind --defauls-file: ExpandConstant(' --defaults-file="{app}\my.ini" MySQLSW')  Now it's perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to use proper function prototypes from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15235687/960757). They're even ANSI and Unicode InnoSetup friendly.