# Run cmd line in AfterInstall event in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to start cmd line in AfterInstall event? Basically, I need to start windows service right after install another programm. I try to do it in [Run]-section, but I failed. So, my idea is to put this line

```
create My_service start=auto binPath=""{app}\My_service.exe""
```

into [Code]-section. How can I do that?

Comment: So [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16521014/960757) didn't work for you ?

Comment: No, it didn't( This code creates the service, but doesn't run it right after install.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's just for creating the service. Then the next line like `Filename: "sc.exe"; Parameters: "start srvname"; Flags: runhidden` should start it.

Comment: Yes, it's works! Thank you!